# Unable to reverse a string using reverse function in <algorithm> in C++

Tags: c++, string, stl, reverse

Following is my code:
I am unable to reverse the string using reverse in file algorithm

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iterator>

using namespace std;
int main()
{ 
 ifstream fp;
 string line;
 fp.open("list");
 if(!fp.is_open())
 {
  cerr<<"file not open";
 }

 while(!fp.eof())
{
  getline(fp,line);
  cout<<line<<end;
  std::reverse(line.begin(),line.end());    
}
```

}

Compilation error I get is:

```
file.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
file.cpp:21:15: error: ‘end’ was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: It is `endl`, not `end`.

Comment: It's the `end` on the line above that is the problem. Voting to close as a question caused by a typo.

Comment: This is a good example of why I like to not have a `using` clause so I end up with `std::endl` instead.

Comment: Or, better still, `'\n'`. Flushing after every line might slow things down somewhat.

Comment: If you think you have a problem reversing a string, then test that with a valid string first. Mixing in IO only confuses the matter.

Comment: *Aside*: Never use `.eof()` or `.good()` as a loop condition. Doing so will usually produce buggy code, as it does here. Try `while ( getline(fp, line) ) { ... }` instead. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it already was said in comments in statement

```
cout<<line<<end;
```

you wrote `end` instead of `endl`

However I would like to say about the algorithm reverse. I do not see a sense in your code because each time variable line is being overwritten. So you do not see the effect of the reversing. Maybe it would be better to write

```
while( getline( fp, line ) )
{
  cout << line << endl;
  std::reverse_copy( line.begin(), line.end(), ostream_iterator<string>( cout, "\n" ) );    
}
```

Only you need to include header `<iterator>`

Also you can reverse an object of type std::string without explicitly using algorithm reverse. For example

```
cout << line << endl;
line.assign( line.rbegin(), line.rend() );
cout << line << endl;
```

or

```
cout << line << endl;
cout << string( line.rbegin(), line.rend() )  << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your string reverse logic is working. The problem is typo :D

```
cout<<line<<end;
```

should be

```
cout<<line<<endl;
```